# How to launch jconsole from Ubuntu 18.04 on Windows 10 WSL

Tags: jconsole

I am trying to launch jconsole on `Ubuntu 18.04` installed on `WSL`(Windows 10).
But it is just hanging there, like waiting for another input or argument.

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin$ ls -lrt jconsole
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 6336 Apr 16 02:48 jconsole
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin$ file jconsole
jconsole: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/l, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=ca8e0f8d1da13af7e272d6ac57781cab9d197b95, stripped
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin$ jconsole
<cursor blinking>
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin$ sudo jconsole
<cursor blinking>
```

Windows version:

```
C:\Users\username>ver

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.1158]
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!